# Why is chess written with a lowercase c whereas the game of Go is written with an uppercase G?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Both *chess* and *Go* are board games. Why the inconsistency in their spelling?

Here are two example usages with *chess* and *Go*:

> It is sometimes called Western chess or international chess to distinguish it from related games such as xiangqi and shogi. Today, chess is one of the world's most popular games, played by millions of people worldwide. - *[Chess/Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess)*

> A 2016 survey by the International Go Federation's 75 member nations found that there are over 46 million people worldwide who know how to play Go and over 20 million current players, the majority of whom live in East Asia. - *[Go (game)/Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game))*

Comment: Answers go in the answer box.

Answer (score 5):

The game of go is not necessarily spelled with a capital 'g', any more than 'chess' begins with a capital 'c'   Here are some dictionary examples.

1. Cambridge English.

> go noun (GAME)
> (also Go)
> a Chinese game played on a square board in which two players try to surround each others' stones (= pieces):

- *Around 50m people in east Asia play go.*

2. Merriam Webster
   Noun (2), (***often capitalised***) <*emphasis my own*

> a game played between two players who alternately place black and white stones on a board checkered by 19 vertical lines and 19 horizontal lines in an attempt to enclose the larger area on the board.

So to the extent to which there is a convention about names of traditional games, such as *chess, scrabble, bridge and others, seems to be not to capitalise them.  The game of go is a late-comer to western countries.  It is likely, also, that frequently the packaging of game sets have all games written either with initial capitals or even using attention seeking capitals throughout.

[*Since writing this, Andrew Leach pointed out an omission I should have thought of myself*.  Some game names (indeed an increasing number, these days) are registered brand names and so a game like "Scrabble") can be written with an initial capital for that reason.  I do not think that prevents someone from writing the name of the game with an initial lower case, however:  no one will successfully sue me for writing *scrabble*, any more than I can be prevented from saying that I have a *hoover* in my cupboard without using a capital letter.]

Merriam Webster is probably the best guide, in offering the initial capital as an alternative.

Comment: See also the (paywalled) OED entries for the games of *[go](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79542), [mah-jong](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112400), [shogi](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178462), [wei ch’i](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226869), [blackjack](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19733), [tennis](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199141), [conkers](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39309), [tag](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197011), [hide-and-seek](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/86727)*. All are given without caps canonically, despite each having at least one capitalized example.

Comment: Games which are trademarks are normally capitalized, like Monopoly, Stratego, etc, older games with generic names are lower-cased. As you say, Go is a late-comer and people may have been unsure whether it was a trademarked name or a generic name, and went by what it said on the box (I'm not sure if there is any legal basis behind capitalizing trademarked names of games). It might be interesting to look at the boxes/instructions for early western versions to see how it was spelt in mid-sentence.

Comment: Scrabble is a trademark and I'd certainly write that with a capital letter.

Comment: @Andrew Leach  Oops!  Yes, of course you are right.  I missed that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The game of ***Go***, whose name in Japanese sounds like the English word "*go*" (or sometimes *igo*) is capitalized in English to prevent it from being mistaken for the English word. Chess does not have a similar problem; chess means chess in all cases. The Japanese character is neither upper or lower case; this distinction does not apply to ideograms.

One might say that Go is capitalized to keep it from getting lost on the page. There is a short discussion about the word and ideogram in the Wikipedia article on [*The History of Go*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Go) which contains an excerpt from *The Diary of Kido Takayoshi*, in which the name of the game is given in lower case.

It is also useful to note that the rules governing the use of capital letters are inconsistent over time and are a matter of convention more than a matter of rules. On this, see Fowler's entry on Capitals: "Apart from certain elementary rules that everyone knows ... their present use is almost as anarchic as that of HYPHENS".